# Efficient bit masking code in C

Tags: c, assembly, bit-manipulation, performance

Since C's bitwise operators `&`, `|`, and `~` are typically also assembly language opcodes as well, bit masking code should in principle be very quick.

I've got some choices of how I add bit-masking inside the inner loop of a simulation algorithm.  Essentially it boils down to the choice between using an array of pre-canned masks, or changing masks dynamically using left and right shifts.

Are there particular tricks / techniques to keep bit-masking as free from unnecessary overhead as possible?  Are any of the three approaches below particularly good / bad from an efficieny point of view?

- Option 1: looping through an array of pre-canned masks, e.g. picking off particular bits

  ```
  unsigned char mask[8]={0x80,0x40,0x20,0x10,0x8,0x4,0x2,0x1};
  for(i=0;i<8;i++) {
      ...
      (mask[i] & mem_data )
      ...
  ```

  }
- Option 2: down-shifting more than one place on each loop iteration

  ```
  unsigned char mask=0x80;
  for(i=0;i<8;i++) {
       ...
       mem_data & (mask>>i)
       ...
  }
  ```
- Option 3: down-shifting exactly one place on each loop iteration

  ```
  unsigned char mask=0x80;
  while(mask) {
        ...
        mem_data & mask
        mask>>=1;
        ...
  }
  ```

**Edit:** *Removed putchar() from the examples so it does not distract from the question*

Comment: I think for any of these the `putchar` is going to be several (at least 3-4) orders of magnitude more expensive, so I'd not worry about it.

Comment: Just profile it and find out. I actually wouldn't be too surprised if the compiler generated very similar code for each one.

Comment: So... you give us the code and want us to profile it for you?

Comment: Agreed. Just profile it for your specific compiler & architecture.

Comment: A good question would be something like "option x is faster than option y, why is that?" (doubt it)

Comment: Option 1 seems kind of weird from a readability standpoint...

Comment: Right, before this gets misinterpreted, I'm hoping for some insight into bit-masking tips / tricks and relative merits of different approaches.  If it's just about profiling, anyone can do that, but I'm hoping the folks on SO can provide more insight.

Comment: @BillyONeal: Good point about `putchar()`.  Would it be reasonable to say ignore the putchar() for now -- it's really the choice between array dereferencing, down-shifting multiple places were iteration, or shifting once per iteration...

Comment: Speed is totally unimportant. For most *general purpose* processors all arithmetic / logic / bitwise operation are equally fast. (this may be a bit different for embedded stuff) On the x86, the operation will cost no cycles if it can be executed in parallel with the bus- and cache traffic. What will cost cycles is the branches (one or two for the loop and one or two for the bit-condition) which will screw the branch prediction and drain the lookahead. The first (LUT) example has the extra disadvantage of wasting a cache slot (but it *could* even be optimised out). YMMV. Measure. Forget it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit masks are often used in the embedded world.

Not all processors can do a bitwise shift with a variable argument. For example, on MSP430 processors you can only bitshift one bit at a time. The implementation will resort to software to shift with a variable amount. In that case the option number 2 has to be avoided. More generally look at the assembly output of your program to compare the most efficient solution.

Comment: Not to mention that none of the above examples result in any bit-shifting being performed. The code is completely optimized out leaving unrolled calls to `putchar`.

Comment: @VladLazarenko This is completely implementation dependent and I'm certain not all implementations will unroll the loop.

Comment: Good answer. Also, it is worth noticing that option 1 might yield array offsetting and/or other pointer manipulation (unless the loop is unrolled by the compiler).